# TikTokApi Problem with Selenium (width) on Colab

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory, tiktok

I am trying to use the TikTokApi package on Google Colab with selenium, but I have a problem with `byUsername` and `getUsername`.
I am executing the following code (that works) to add TikTokApi and chromedriver:

```
!pip install TikTokApi
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
```

then I am getting an instance of the api

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
api = TikTokApi.get_instance(use_selenium = True, executablePath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver")
```

Now if I use `getUsername`:

```
username = 'fcbarcelona'
l = api.getUser(username)
```

I get a result (16 videos). On the other side when I use `byUsername`, it raised me an error

```
username = 'fcbarcelona'
user_videos = api.byUsername(username,count = 20)
```

The error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/TikTokApi/tiktok.py in __add_new_params__(self)
   1642             "user_agent": self.__format_new_params__(self.userAgent),
   1643             "cookie_enabled": "true",
-> 1644             "screen_width": self.width,
   1645             "screen_height": self.height,
   1646             "browser_language": self.browser_language,

AttributeError: 'TikTokApi' object has no attribute 'width'
```

As far as I have understood this problem is due to selenium not correctly installed, even tough I ve yet used on Colab and the previous part of the code works fine. Also I don't understand the difference between `byUsername` and `getUsername`. Maybe I am doing something wrong on Colab with selenium, but I dont know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here in the github issue [[INSTALLATION/BUG] - Selenium and Google Colab #548](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues/548):

> I am closing this issue with the [@mathigatti](https://github.com/mathigatti) [solution](https://github.com/mathigatti)
>
> ```
> !pip install TikTokApi
> !python -m pip install playwright
> !apt install libgstreamer1.0-0 libwoff1 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0
> %%writefile test.py
> from TikTokApi import TikTokApi 
> #your code
> ```
>
> Then
>
> ```
> !python test.py
> ```